# How can callback handle variable number of multiple inputs in Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I would like to develop a program that is able to dynamically compute the mean for different types of distributions (normal, lognormal). The distribution functions require two respectively three input parameters.

My callback returns an: “A nonexistent object was used in an Input …” error since always three input parameters are passed to the function.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks

```
import dash
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

#app = dash.Dash()
app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP], suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody([
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([

                dbc.Row([
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='dd-dist',
                        clearable = False,
                        options=[
                            {'label': 'Normal', 'value': 'NOR'},
                            {'label': 'Log-Normal', 'value': 'LGN'},
                        ], 
                        style={'width': '60%'},
                        value='LGN'
                    )
                ],),



                html.Div(
                    id='parameter-input'
                ),

                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col([
                        html.H5('Mean')
                    ],width={'size': 5, 'offset': 0}),
                    dbc.Col([
                        dcc.Input(
                            id='mean-out',
                            value= None,
                        )
                    ]) 
                ]),



            ], width={'size': 4, 'offset': 0, 'order': 1}),

        ], align='center'),

    ])
)

], style={'padding': 10})



@app.callback(
    Output('parameter-input', 'children'),
    [Input('dd-dist', 'value')])
def update_parameter(value):
    if 'LGN' == value:
        return (dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col([
                        html.H5('Shape')
                    ],width={'size': 5, 'offset': 0}),
                    dbc.Col([
                        dcc.Input(
                            id='param1-in',
                            debounce = True,
                            value = 1,
                            min= 0,
                            max= 10,
                            style = {'fontSize': 14}
                        )
                    ],width={'size': 4, 'offset': 0}, align='end')


                ]),

            dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col([
                        html.H5('Location')
                    ],width={'size': 5, 'offset': 0}),
                    dbc.Col([
                        dcc.Input(
                            id='param2-in',
                            debounce = True,
                            value = 1,
                            min=0,
                            max=5,
                            style = {'fontSize': 14}
                        )
                    ],width={'size': 4, 'offset': 0}, align='end')


                ]),

            dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col([
                        html.H5('Scale')
                    ],width={'size': 5, 'offset': 0}),
                    dbc.Col([
                        dcc.Input(
                            id='param3-in',
                            debounce = True,
                            value = 1,
                            min=0,
                            max=5,
                            style = {'fontSize': 14}
                        )
                    ],width={'size': 4, 'offset': 0}, align='end')


                ])
        )

    elif 'NOR' == value:
        return (dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col([
                        html.H5('Mean')
                    ],width={'size': 5, 'offset': 0}),
                    dbc.Col([
                        dcc.Input(
                            id='param1-in',
                            debounce = True,
                            value = 1,
                            min= 0,
                            max= 10,
                            style = {'fontSize': 14}
                        )
                    ],width={'size': 4, 'offset': 0}, align='end')


                ]),

            dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col([
                        html.H5('Standard deviation')
                    ],width={'size': 5, 'offset': 0}),
                    dbc.Col([
                        dcc.Input(
                            id='param2-in',
                            debounce = True,
                            value = 1,
                            min=0,
                            max=5,
                            style = {'fontSize': 14}
                        )
                    ],width={'size': 4, 'offset': 0}, align='end')
            ])
        )

@app.callback(
    Output('mean-out', 'value'),
    [Input('dd-dist', 'value'),
     Input('param1-in', 'value'),
     Input('param2-in', 'value'),
     Input('param3-in', 'value')
     ]
)
def return_mean(dist, param1, param2, param3):
    if dist == 'LGN':
        return round(stats.lognorm.mean(float(param1), float(param2), float(param3)), 3)
    elif dist == 'NOR':
        return round(stats.norm.mean(float(param1), float(param2)), 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(mode='external')
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be misinterpreting this but it seems to me like you want a varying number of arguments. The proper way to do this in python is this syntax:

```
def test(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

This function will accept any number of inputs and print them in order as the *args creates a list of all the trailing arguments. It should be noted that positional arguments can still be placed before this and it will not raise an error if it receives no arguments, it only creates an empty list.

Make sure to comment if you have any questions or if this was not what you were asking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like it is not that easy since you have to provide the exact number of inputs in the callback function.

Comment: I'm using this exact solution and it looks like *args works in callbacks